# Is it possible to construct the letter 's' out of flat shapes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am looking to learn how to create my own text logos, without using any typefaces. This particular design is to feature the word 'swerve', but I'm having a difficult time with the letter 's'. All the other letters have been built by adding and subtracting shapes, but I find it extremely difficult to construct an 's' shape that does not look out of place. Is it possible to build an 's' shape out of flat shapes, by for example adding and subtracting layers of circles, or do I have to play with the pen tool until I get it right?

Note: I'm using Photoshop CS6.

This is the design that I'm going for:

[image]

Comment: As the responses show, this is an interesting exercise! But please, do not construct your logo on Photoshop. Try using Illustrator or Inkscape if you want a free program.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the look of what you supplied, here is what I would recommend:
[image]

For further clarity:
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate why the circles are not on the same height? What "rule" or idea made you place the circles in that way? How did you choose that distance?

Comment: I've updated the graphic. The arcs are each 1 quarter of a complete circle. They are centered to each other. The vertical offset is somewhat arbitrary, but is based on the height of the horizontal connector. That measurement is flexible, should probably be adjusted to best suit the height of your other letters.

Answer (score 6):

well, you could do something like this:

[image]

which is based on your current e character

[image]

and if you want, instead of using triangles you can use rectangles for a straight horizontal line on the terminals, as follows:

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it. :) These look most in keeping with the rest of the letters IMO.

Comment: The only suggestion that doesn't feel very awkward to me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one.

Small E is flipped, rotated and clipped to get the s. The blue text is a readability test. Maybe you need a little thicker v and r or thinned e and s.

[image]

Not asked, but maybe useful:

Thin v is tried to be fixed by pasting a little horizontally shifted copy onto it. The r had got a full height stake. The new s is stretched a little higher than e.

[image]

Comment: It looks a bit like the S would fall to the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example - this was done in Illustrator CC 2017 with the Shaper Tool, but I suppose you could something similar in PS, but not as easily. Anyhoo, I'm sure you'll get the idea. It's made from two ellipses and two rectangles.

[image]